# regex to find a 44 length string after " - "

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that will find a string length of 44 digits / letters:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{44,}$
```

the problem is that my text file is built like that:

```
XXXXX - SOMETHINGSOMETHINGSOMETHING55252
XXXXX - SOMETHINGSOMETHING985295829
```

So, I want the search to start after the "space - space" I tried to do it by my self with out success :( Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove `^`, if there are just letters and digits at the end of string after `-`, it will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=- )[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/a5CpMU/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
- Positive Lookbehind (?<=- ) assert that the Regex below matches the characters "- " literally (case sensitive) on the left
- [A-Za-z0-9]+ - Match a single character present in the [A-Za-z0-9] list between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- $ - asserts position at the end of a line
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to specify the length I'm searching for as well?

Comment: Thanks, I edited it a little bit so it will look for 44 length and special characters as well.
(?<=- )[a-zA-Z0-9!@%=#$&()\-`.+,/"]{44,}$